# Vert.x ReadStream<Buffer> to InputStream

Tags: jersey, vert.x

I am trying to set up Vert.X with Jersey to handle POST data (not necessarily form data).

The Jersey `ContainerRequest.setEntityStream` takes in an `InputStream` which is what I am trying to build.  However, I can't seem to get around passing that data without reading the whole thing into memory using `bodyHandler` or my own custom method that does something similar but limits the input

```
    final Buffer body = Buffer.buffer();
    event
        .handler(buffer -> {
            if (!event.response().headWritten()) {
                body.appendBuffer(buffer);
                if (body.length() > 10 * 1024 * 1024) {
                    event.response()
                        .setStatusCode(REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.getStatusCode())
                        .setStatusMessage(REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.getReasonPhrase())
                        .end();
                }
            }
        })
        .endHandler(aVoid -> {
            request.setEntityStream(new VertxBufferInputStream(body));
            appHandler.handle(request);
        });
```

`VertxBufferInputStream` is a simple wrapper to the VertXbuffer.  Just to save some memory by avoiding converting to a ByteArrayInputStream().  But it has the whole body.

I want to avoid having the whole body and have it streamed.  I've tried a few things all pretty hacky and bad code that eventually does not work because it blocks the event loop because the `handler` is not called and is waiting for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two components that are needed.

1. you need to make sure you separate the processing for anything that may block using `vertx.executeBlocking` see https://github.com/trajano/app-ms/blob/7f1de326683473839ffe85fe711cbe719f7a0a74/ms-engine/src/main/java/net/trajano/ms/engine/JaxRsRoute.java#L128
2. you need to handle two events: when new buffer of data comes in and when it ends.  https://github.com/trajano/app-ms/blob/7f1de326683473839ffe85fe711cbe719f7a0a74/ms-engine/src/main/java/net/trajano/ms/engine/JaxRsRoute.java#L123
3. you need to implement an InputStream that would be able to accept data from another thread and block when there is no data along with the capability of receiving a message that there is no more input.
   https://github.com/trajano/app-ms/blob/master/ms-engine/src/main/java/net/trajano/ms/engine/internal/VertxBlockingInputStream.java

Answer (score 0):

Such a beautiful problem to solve :) 
You can get an inspiration at https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/12e5d8bdf22bcd2676a1032ed69473cf2bbc48c7/containers/netty-http/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/netty/httpserver/JerseyHttp2ServerHandler.java#L124
where Jersey integration with Netty is implemented.

I believe there are exactly the same problems solved (although for a different webserver, Netty in this case), that is:

1. The http request is handled on an event loop (by Netty), as such the `ApplicationHandler.handle()` method has to be called on a different thread (non event loop)
2. Non blocking API has to be converted to blocking `InputStream`. That is implemented at `NettyInputStream`. It takes advantage of the fact that Netty's `ByteBuf` can be easily converted to an `InputStream` and as a result by using `LinkedBlockingDeque` these InputStreams are converted to a single one. (Just fyi, I'm not 100% sure if the provider, the event loop thread, is guarantied to never block which would be a bug.)

By the way, this is just a processing of the incoming data. For the response, you'll have to implement a conversion of `OutputStream` (used by Jersey) to Vert.X non-blocking API.

Comment: Thanks I also looked into it.  One of my attempts was similar to that but it still blocks because "take()" will block.

Comment: I don't understand. That's perfectly ok; `take()` is blocking (that's the contract of `InputStream.read()`). The important part is what I described at [1], the `ApplicationHandler.handle()` has to be delegated to a different thread. As a consequence, the `take()` method is called by this other thread and everything works perfectly. There's no other way than this unless Jersey came with non-blocking API which didin't happen (unfortunately; but it was close).

Comment: Correct it is the closest one.  (I just got it working right now)